Could not find error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar
I am working on KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform for Mobile) and while upgrading android and common dependencies (kotlin: 1.9.20, Gradle Plugin: 8.1.0), I have encountered a weird issue.
Task failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:extractDebugAnnotations'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not find error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.11.0).
Searched in the following locations:
../maven/v1/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar

Checked all the dependencies and found this lib is used in com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre
\--- com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage:31.1.2
+--- com.android.tools:common:31.1.2
|    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:31.1.2
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.12.0
|    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.11.0
|    |    --- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
|    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0
|    |    --- net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.6.0
|    --- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.20-RC2
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20-RC2
|         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.20-RC2
|         |    --- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|         --- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.20-RC2
|              --- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20-RC2 (*)
+--- com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:31.1.2
|    --- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.19.3
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.20-RC2 (*)
+--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.19.3
\--- com.google.testing.platform:android-device-provider-local:0.0.8-alpha08

I have tried to exclude the dependency, enforce the version 2.11.0 or even the latest one 2.24.0, but nothing worked. Even tried to clear Android studio completely but no luck.
While trying to execute the gradle task "publishIosPublicationToMavenLocal", I am getting this error:
Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:extractDebugAnnotations'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not find error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.11.0).
Searched in the following locations:
../maven/v1/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 40s
55 actionable tasks: 21 executed, 21 from cache, 13 up-to-date
Platforms
Android, Java 17
